# Multiple Like Clauses Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a search box for my website. In my user accounts table, I've divided the accounts into three, namely homeowners, admins, and deactivated users. I want the search function to be able to search across multiple columns (search by username, first name, last name, address, combination of first name and last name). However in my model, my WHERE clause seems to be ignored. In my search_homeowner function, I limit the results to display only the homeowners, but I get results that show the admin ones. I can't seem to have multiple LIKEs so I tried OR like. Here's the code.

Model:

```
function search_homeowner($searchquery) {

    $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where('role', 0)-> where('isActive', 1);
    $this->db->like('firstname',$searchquery,'after');
    $this->db->or_like('lastname',$searchquery,'after');
    $this->db->or_like('username',$searchquery,'after');
    $this->db->or_like('address',$searchquery,'after'); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function search_homeowner() {
     $this->load->model('model_accounts');
     $searchquery = $this->input->post('search');

     if(isset($searchquery) and !empty($searchquery)) {
        $data['users'] = $this->model_accounts->search_homeowner($searchquery);
        $data['main_content'] = 'view_adminaccounts';
        $data['homeownerlinks']='';
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_accounts_template', $data);
     } else {
        redirect('admin_accounts/homeowner');
     }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 $whereaccounts=array('role'=>0,'isActive'=>1);
 $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where($whereaccounts);
 $this->db->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
 $this->db->where('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
 $this->db->where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
 $this->db->where('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchquery . '%');
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but when I press the search button, now it does not display any records

Comment: keep print_r($this->db->last_query); under $query = $this->db->get(); this particular line you will get the query check once and execute once in database you will get the point where mistake is going exacty..

Comment: Now, it displays `SELECT * FROM 'accounts' WHERE 'role' =0 AND 'isActive' = 1 AND 'firstname' = 'LIKE' AND 'lastname' = 'LIKE' AND 'username' = 'LIKE' AND 'address' = 'LIKE'` . The `$searchquery` seems to be not read

Comment: write not empty condition  for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132066/discussion-between-coderszx-and-soniya-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

The or_like ci method you are using after which is prints "searchstring%". If you removed that it will be printed like this "%searchstring%". So please try like this

```
   function search_homeowner($searchquery) {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where('role', 0)-> where('isActive', 1);
        $this->db->like('firstname',$searchquery);
        $this->db->or_like('lastname',$searchquery);
        $this->db->or_like('username',$searchquery);
        $this->db->or_like('address',$searchquery); 

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you bother writing an `if` block if both outcomes perform the same action?  Also, `->select('*')` is unnecessary.  Why do you mix method chaining with non-chaining techniques?